# Log axis looses minor ticks sometimes with Pandas plot

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

The exact same code sometimes produces minor ticks, sometimes none, depending on the dataset. Starting from a Pandas dataframe df,

```
ax = df.plot(x=0, y=1, logy=True, ylabel=df.columns[1], grid=True)
ax.yaxis.grid(which='minor', linewidth=0.5) # Probably not related to the problem
```

How to make sure that minor ticks are always present? This is with matplotlib 3.5.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding the following code seems to always result in the wanted minor ticks.

```
ax.yaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LogLocator(subs=(1,),
                                             numticks=12))
ax.yaxis.set_minor_locator(ticker.LogLocator(subs=0.2*np.arange(1,5),
                                             numticks=12))
```

The number 12 is not magic: it just needs to be larger than the number of decades covering the data. But `subs=(1,)` is the key as it forces matplotlib to have one major tick per decade. At least, that's what it seems. Matplotlib is so finicky and so prone to fail...

[image]